# Paypal Payment Notification

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

I would like to have the Notification like if the transaction made is success or failure.

My Code :

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<!--<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="T4ETNVYF7D898">
-->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="uresh._1304751477_biz@yahoo.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Ramakdu">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/paypal/">


<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/WEBSCR-640-20110429-1/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/WEBSCR-640-20110429-1/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

<?php
    print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

Comment: What is your question? IPN has numerous PHP examples at the [PayPal developer network](http://www.x.com), e.g. [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNImplementation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example.com/paymentsuccess" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://example.com/paymentsuccess">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://example.com/paymentfailure" />
```

Return should be a link and not "localhost".

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that "notify_url" **must** be a publicly accessible URL. Return will work for testing, but notify_url is a POST initiated from the PayPal-side, and must thus be publicly acc